# Как заставить тег Select динамически менять свой размер

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача сделать тег Select что бы он принимал размер выбранной опции. Скажем есть код

```
<select id="orient">
    <option value="op">Много слово очень много слов, прям очень много</option>
    <option value="ol">Мало слов </option>
</select>
```

При выборе опции op размер тега должен быть равен этой опции.
Ну а при выборе  ol размер тега должен быть в разы меньше.
Знаю что по умолчанию размер тега select равен размеру самой большой его опции. Как это обойти?

Answer (score 0):

> Как это обойти?

Колхозить.

```js
document.querySelector('#orient').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var ghost = document.createElement('span'); // создаём элемент
  
  ghost.textContent = target.options[target.selectedIndex].textContent; // добавляем туда текст
  ghost.style.font = getComputedStyle(target).font; // задаём такие же стили текста, как у селекта, чтобы правильно считался размер
  ghost.style.visibility = 'collapse'; // Скрываем с глаз долой, на всякий пожарный.
  document.body.append(ghost); // Добавляем на страницу
  target.style.width = ghost.getBoundingClientRect().width + 30 +'px'; // Получаем ширину текста + 30 (длина стрелки) и всё это ставим в ширину селекта
  
  ghost.remove(); // Удаляем элмент, он нам больше не нужен.
})
```

```html
<select id="orient">
  <option value="op">Много слово очень много слов, прям очень много</option>
  <option value="ol">Мало слов </option>
</select>
```

Описание в комментариях к коду.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало! Осталась проблема что изначальный размер тега был равен  максимальному, но динамически менялся при изменении опции. Но я решил это через CSS задав ширину тега равному значению стандартно выбранной опции. Еще раз спасибо!!!

Comment: @МаксимСмоленский, можно при загрузки DOM определять длину селекта и устанавливать её как `max-width`. Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.